# Is there a way to get online users count for a Facebook group?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

You have Graph Api, and you have the token of the user. When a user is member of a group, and we know the group ID.

Is there a way to get the online users count of a Facebook group via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question:

> Is there a way to get the online users count of a Facebook group via
>   the API?

**NO**, you can't.

The closest result you can get is by using the `members` connection of the [group object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/):

> All of the users who are members of this group (can only currently
>   return the first 500 members).